# Why does replace not work for this substring?

Tags: python

I'm completely new to Python so I apologize in advance for the bad code. I am trying to replace the sub-string of strings in a list, but the list returned is the same. In the code, there is a list of accounts and another list of transactions given by the user, I am supposed to check whether the command is add or sub to either add to balance or subtract from it. Here is the format for both lists:

```
F1:
ACCOUNT NUMBER | PIN CODE | BALANCE
F2:
COMMAND | AMOUNT | ACCOUNT NUMBER | PIN CODE
```

And here is the code I'm working with:

```
import sys

F1 = sys.argv[1]
F2 = sys.argv[2]


def file_reader(filePath):
    file = open(filePath, 'r')
    data = file.read()
    file.close()
    return data


def splitter(str):
    return str.split()


def joiner(list):
    return '\n'.join(list)


def file_writer(filePath, str):
    file = open(filePath, 'w')
    file.write(str)


def make_transaction(accounts, transactions):
    for i in range(len(transactions)):
        # Check account number & pin
        if accounts[i][0:4] == transactions[i][9:13]:
            if accounts[i][5:9] == transactions[i][-4:]:
                # Check whether the user wants to add or subtract from balance
                if 'add' in transactions[i]:
                    balance = int(accounts[i][10:])
                    transaction = int(transactions[i][4:8])
                    balance += transaction
                    balanceStr = str(balance)
                    accounts[i].replace(accounts[i][10:], balanceStr)
                elif 'sub' in transactions[i]:
                    balance = int(accounts[i][10:])
                    transaction = int(transactions[i][4:8])
                    if balance > transaction:
                        balance -= transaction
                        balanceStr = str(balance)
                        accounts[i].replace(accounts[i][10:], balanceStr)
    return accounts


file1 = fileReader(F1)
file1Data = splitter(file1)
file2 = fileReader(F2)
file2Data = splitter(file2)

print(file1Data)
print(file2Data)
print(makeTransaction(file1Data, file2Data))
```

This is the output:

```
Program Failed for Input: /tmp/a1 /tmp/tx
Expected Output: 
Your Program Output: ['1000|1234|10000', '1020|2222|0', '3000|3344|1000', '2020|1234|90000']
['add|1000|1000|1234', 'sub|1000|1020|2222', 'sub|1000|3000|3344']
['1000|1234|10000', '1020|2222|0', '3000|3344|1000', '2020|1234|90000']
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. I think you can, and should, get rid of the `fileWriter()`, `splitter()`, and `joiner()` functions. Naming variables `str` or `list` is a bad idea, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

`.replace` is risky use case for what you are trying to solve. It is using pattern matching to do the change and in case your substring, i.e. `balance[10:]` would accidentally match with `balance[0:5]` you would silently get very unpredictable results.

Instead, I would suggest you replace

```
 accounts[i].replace(accounts[i][10:], balanceStr)
```

with

```
accounts[i] = accounts[i][0:9] + balanceStr
```

On an extra note, assuming that your input data is split by `|`, you should create data holders for your input data instead of working with the strings as the strings are volatile and your code could start acting unpredictably if your customer performed a very large transaction.

I would instead do something along the lines of `account_number, pin_code, balance = '1000|1234|10000'.split('|')` and load the data into a list where each row would represent one account or one transaction.

Comment: Note that the `csv` module can be trivially made to parse pipe-separated data, making it possible to write a simple `for` loop that unpacks one parsed line from each file on each loop, as in your final `split` and unpack example.

Answer (score 0):

This should be completely rewritten:

```
def make_transaction(accounts, transactions):
    for i in range(len(transactions)):
        # Check account number & pin
        if accounts[i][0:4] == transactions[i][9:13]:
            if accounts[i][5:9] == transactions[i][-4:]:
                # Check whether the user wants to add or subtract from balance
                if 'add' in transactions[i]:
                    balance = int(accounts[i][10:])
                    transaction = int(transactions[i][4:8])
                    balance += transaction
                    balanceStr = str(balance)
                    accounts[i].replace(accounts[i][10:], balanceStr)
                elif 'sub' in transactions[i]:
                    balance = int(accounts[i][10:])
                    transaction = int(transactions[i][4:8])
                    if balance > transaction:
                        balance -= transaction
                        balanceStr = str(balance)
                        accounts[i].replace(accounts[i][10:], balanceStr)
    return accounts
```

for example, I'd rather do this:

```
def make_transaction(accounts, transactions) :
    for a,t in zip(accounts, transactions) :
        a_num, a_pin, a_balance = a.split('|')
        t_command, t_amount, t_num, t_pin = t.split('|')
        if a_num == t_num and a_pin == t_pin :
            if t_command == 'add' :
                # do your stuff
            elif t_command == 'sub' :
                # do something else
```

and so on... working on string with indices is very very wrong.

Comment: Thank you, could you elaborate on why it's not a good idea to use indices on strings?

Comment: @DiegoVasquez take for example F2: `COMMAND | AMOUNT | ACCOUNT NUMBER | PIN CODE` -- the amount can change from `0` to `12` to `123` to `12345` and probably even to `82344762387` -- if you work with indices, you have to accomodate all possible string lenght or your code gets broken. Splitting the string using separators will always work, no matter how long are the strings inside.